# Is it possible to serve static HTML without the file extension?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a ruby + sinatra website where most of the files are static HTML, meaning they can be accessed by going to http://www.mydomain.com/features.html, http://www.mydomain.com/pricing.html, etc... (I am using sinatra for a few more dynamic pages)

What I would like to do is serve these static HTML files without their file extensions.  So going to http://www.mydomain.com/features would show the same as if I currently visited http://www.mydomain.com/features.html currently.

I have tried simply removing my .html file extensions, however when trying to open these files in the browser, the browser downloads downloads the file instead of rendering it on screen.

Is it possible to continue serving my static .html files just without their file extensions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/:file_name' do |fname| 
  send_file(
    File.join(settings.public_folder, "#{fname}.html")
  )
end
```

...then either url:

> http://www.mydomain.com/features.html
>   http://www.mydomain.com/features

will return the same page.

> **settings.public_folder**: By default, this is assumed to be a directory
>   named “public” within the root directory...http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

If you define the routes for your dynamic pages above that route, then they will match first.